# Node.js and Express: Updating router.get and res.render's object after load

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I have this code, which is returns the following error on `req.body.firstname.length` inside `router.use` on the page load:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Because already checking the input forms value and the default value is `undefined`. I want to only check this code when it's getting `req.xhr` request from the AJAX form, not on the page load. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body.firstname.length === 0) {
    var validateFirstname = false;
  } else {
    var validateFirstname = true;
  };
  if(validateFirstname === true && validateCaptcha === true) {
    console.log('SUCCESS: Form validated!');
  } else {
    console.log('ERROR: Form not validated!');
  };
  next();
});
```

The reason why it's in a `router.use`, not in `router.post`, because I want to share this logic for `router.get` also, where my template rendering resides.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the relevant full code to get the idea what's going on:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Nodemailer MIDDLEWARE
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const firstname = req.body.firstname;
  req.firstname = firstname;

  if(req.firstname.length === 0) {
    var validateFirstname = false;
  } else {
    var validateFirstname = true;
  };

  if(validateFirstname === true) {
    console.log('SUCCESS: Form validated!');
    // send mail with defined transport object
    req.sending = true;
  } else {
    console.log('ERROR: Form not validated!');
    req.sending = false;
  };

  next();
});

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  req.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    ...
  });
  // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
  req.mailOptions = {
    ...
  };
  next();
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Nodemailer
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.xhr && req.sending === true) {
    // send mail with defined transport object
    req.transporter.sendMail(req.mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Error occurred');
        console.log(err.message);
      }
      console.log('Message sent successfully!');
      console.log('Server responded with "%s"', info.response);
      res.send('<div class="form-validation-success">SUCCESS: Message sent successfully!</div>');
    });
  } else {
    res.send('<div class="form-validation-error">ERROR: Message cannot be sent!</div>');
  };

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// INTERNAL API
// GET Contact page
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('contact', {
    title: 'Contact',
    formValidationError: req.displayBlock
  });
});
```

In my handebars template:

```
<div id="responseText"></div>
```

This code is now working but not updating the already rendered viewing template. I guess to only way to solve this to handle the server's response with AJAX, but how? This is the client-side AJAX code:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  document.getElementById('xhr').onclick = function() { makeRequest(); };

  function makeRequest() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var data = { firstname: firstname };
    // instance of a class that provides this functionality
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // decide what you want to do after you receive the server response to your request
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      try {
        // process the server response
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
          // everything is good, the response is received
          //alert(xhr.responseText);
          document.getElementById('responseText').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        } else {
          // still not ready
          alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        };
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
      };
    };
    // make the request
    xhr.open('POST', '/en/contact', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
})();
```

It's always returning the `There was a problem with the request` error message, even when also returning `xhr.responseText`.

This router file resides at `routes/contact.js` and handling the requests at `/:lang/contact`. That's why you see `'/'` url in the file.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, there is no `req.body` for GET requests, how you want to reuse that?

Answer (score 0):

can you please add some more information on it....as it is very difficult to figure out the problem with this information.

you are trying a post on uri /en/contact
but receiving a request on /

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sepcific about this one. This is a router which is at `routes/contact.js` and handling the requests at `/:lang/contact`.